# Pymongo: insert_many() gives "TypeError: document must be instance of dict" for list of dicts

Tags: pymongo, python-3.6

I haven't been able to find any relevant solutions to my problem when googling, so I thought I'd try here.

I have a program where I parse though folders for a certain kind of trace files, and then save these in a MongoDB database. Like so:

```
posts = function(source_path)
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client.database
collection = db.collection
insert = collection.insert_many(posts)

def function(...):
    ....
    post = parse(trace)
    posts.append(post)
    return posts

def parse(...):
    ....
    post = {'Thing1': thing,
            'Thing2': other_thing,
            etc}
    return post
```

However, when I get to "insert = collection.insert_many(posts)", it returns an error:

```
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

According to the debugger, "posts" is a list of about 1000 dicts, which should be vaild input according to all of my research. If I construct a smaller list of dicts and insert_many(), it works flawlessly.

Does anyone know what the issue may be?

Answer (score 0):

Some more debugging revealed the issue to be that the "parse" function sometimes returned None rather than a dict. Easily fixed.